# Lower bounds for non-parametric regression in sup-norm with bounded noise

Tags: regression, nonparametric, convergence

It is well-known that lower bounds on the nonparametric regression convergence rates under Gaussian (and more general unbounded) noise assumptions are given by $n^{-\frac{\beta}{2\beta + d}}$ in the $L^2$ case and by $(\frac{n}{log(n)})^{-\frac{\beta}{2\beta + d}}$ in the sup-norm case (see papers by Stone (1980,1982)) where $d$ represents the dimensionality of input space and $\beta$ is the Holder exponent of the class of functions on which the convergence rate is computed. When the noise is assumed bounded (let us assume a uniform distribution for simplicity), we have that the lower bound on the nonparametric convergence rates can be improved to: $n^{-\frac{\beta}{\beta + 1}}$ in the 1-dimensional case (e.g. see exercise 2.7 in Introduction to Non-parametric Estimation).

I was wondering if there are existing results that provide a similar lower bound in the sup-norm (uniform convergence) and bounded noise case? And whether these results would then hold for the $d$-dimensional setting?

Thank you!